# Set html id attribute dynamically in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to set the id of an element using a variable in a Twig template (not a form) without using JavaScript. 
The template code looks like this:

```
{% set show_id = 'show' ~ entity.id %}
{{ dump(show_id) }}
<div class="event_option" id="show_id">
    <a href="{{ path('event_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">show</a>
</div>
```

The show_id variable is `dump`'ed correctly, but when I try to use it as the html id in `id="show_id"`, the id that gets assigned to the div is the string "show_id", and not the actual value of `show_id`. I get the same result when no parenthesis are used when assigning the html id, as in `id=show_id`. How can I access the Twig variable when assigning the html id attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enclose with double bracket to tell Twig to print the value of variable

```
<div class="event_option" id="{{show_id}}">
    <a href="{{ path('event_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">show</a>
</div>
```